# How to use Moq object correctly when object is parameter in method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary

I am not completely new to unit testing, however I am new to the Moq library and I have run into a problem. I am confused on why my unit test fails. Here is the unit test I am trying to write.

```
[TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        //...
        optionsMock = new Mock<IDictionary<string, string>>();
        //...
    }

[TestMethod]
    public void TestFunction()
    {
        // Arrange
        //var options = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { keyValue, true.ToString() } }; // only way to get the unit test to pass right now
        optionsMock.Setup(a => a.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(b => b == keyValue))).Returns(false);
        optionsMock.Setup(c => c.Add(It.Is<string>(d => d == keyValue), It.Is<string>(e => e == true.ToString()))).Verifiable();
        optionsMock.Setup(f => f.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(g => g == keyValue))).Returns(true);
        optionsMock.Setup(h => h[It.Is<string>(i => i == keyValue)]).Returns(true.ToString()); 

        // Act
        int projectId = sut.Open(stringValue, booleanValue, stringValue, stringValue, IDictionary<string, string>, out errorString);

        // Assert
        optionsMock.Verify(a => a.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(b => b == keyValue)), Times.Once());
        optionsMock.Verify(c => c.Add(It.Is<string>(d => d == keyValue), It.Is<string>(e => e == true.ToString())), Times.Once());
        optionsMock.Verify(f => f.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(g => g == keyValue)), Times.Once());
        optionsMock.Verify(h => h[It.Is<string>(i => i == keyValue)], Times.Once()); // This fails 
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, id); // This fails even if I remove the line above
    }
```

The line commented out is the only way I can get the test to pass, but I feel I should be able to use a mock dictionary as well. The problem I am experiencing is that eventually sut.Open(...) makes a call to an internal class that has an IDictionary as a parameter. In that method there is a check to see if the dictionary is null. Whenever I run the unit test without a real dictionary, the null check always evaluates to true and I get a false fail. However if the real dictionary is passed in, I get a passing test. Here is an example of the internal code.

```
public int Open(..., IDictionary<string, string> dictionary, ...)
    {
        //...
        if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
           dictionary.Add(key, true);
        }

        InternalClass.Method(dictionary);
        //...
    }
```

Here is the internal classes method

```
public void Method(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
       if(dictionary != null && dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
       {
          string value = dictionary[key];
          //... Do something
       }
       else
       {
          //... Do something else
       }
    }
```

It always executes Do something else, is there away around this?

Comment: You can pass the instance of that Internal class as Dependency Injection, and mock the validator method that throws exception?

Comment: Can you update the question with your attempt at creating a Mock<IDictionary<string,string>> ? I assume that's what you're doing

Comment: Will update with declaration of mock

Comment: I would love to inject the internal class into my sut class, however that is not possible in this situation. I would imagine that would pretty much solve my problem :(.

Comment: Can you post a complete the code which has the behavior that is failing? Your code sample has a bunch of commented out lines so it's not clear whether that's what you want or not. Also your `sut.Open` call has a parameter that is just a type (`IDictionary<string, string>`) as well as the `InternalClass.Method` call. This presents an unclear picture of what your situation really is.

Comment: Ok I will update with hopefully a clearer picture of what is going on.

Comment: Updated with some new information that hopefully clears up any confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look closer to the following line:

```
optionsMock.Setup(a => a.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(b => b == keyValue))).Returns(false);
```

This means `ContainsKey` should return `false`. So the condition:

```
if (dictionary != null && dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
```

can never be satisfied.

I guess you meant to write `.Returns(true);`

Comment: Ugh, yes this was what I was trying to do.

Comment: That was definitely an issue but now I fail on the add call, I will update the code section to show where I am using that.

Comment: Oh I see, I have two different scenarios where I use dictionary.ContainsKey, one where it is suppose to be false the other were it is suppose to be true!

Comment: You can setup two different cases (repeat the `.Setup` call with different parameters in `It.Is`), or you can pass a lambda to `.Return`

Comment: Hmm, can I have two separate calls to the same moq function and have different return values?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, if you have two different inputs, you just call `Setup` twice. If it's for a single input, call `Setup` once but pass a lambda to `Returns` and do your logic there.

Comment: Sorry for some reason the comment wasn't there when I posted. Anyhow I will try this out!

Comment: When I put another SetUp it doesn't seem to separate the two from each other. Here is what the output says:

Comment: Expected invocation on mock once but was 2 times: a => a.ContainsKey(It.IsAny<string>(b => b.fullPath). I will update the code with this new information

Comment: That's because your two `Setup` calls have identical parameters, the second call supersedes the first.

Comment: How would I push the logic into the return call as you suggested before? I am not clear how I would accomplish that

Comment: `.Returns(() => yourCondition ? someResult : someOtherResult)`, or even `.Returns(() => { if (something) { return someResult; } return otherResult; })`

Answer (score -1):

Alright so I think this is the answer I am happy with. I found some other places online where this was used by other people as well. Here is the Setup and Verify section now

```
bool firstCall = true;

        optionsMock.Setup(a => a.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(b => b == keyValue))).Returns(() =>
        {
            if (firstCall)
            {
                firstCall = false;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
```

Then I verify below with the following:

```
optionsMock.Verify(a => a.ContainsKey(It.Is<string>(b => b == fullPath)), Times.Exactly(2));
```

The only thing I don't like about this, is the added logic in the test :(. However I don't see any other way around it. Thanks for all the help!